# Entity Framework Code First Repository really generic and problems with two context

Tags: c#, repository-pattern, entity-framework-4.1

sorry my bad English.
In company where I work we are migrating for Entity Framework Code First.
But problems happen when i create two instance of repository

```
RepositoryGeneric<Anuncio> repAnuncio1 = new RepositoryGeneric<Anuncio>();
Anuncio anuncio1 = repAnuncio1.find(1)

Anuncio anuncio2 = new Anuncio (1,20,"any thing");

RepositoryGeneric<Anuncio> repAnuncio2 = new RepositoryGeneric<Anuncio>();

repAnuncio2.salvar(anuncio2); //ok work

repAnuncio2.salvar(anuncio1); // error the anuncio1 is atach in repAnuncio1
```

it is only exemple, but in real application i need several repository interacting.

else, we application use DataContext:

```
  public static void Save(Entity entity)
  {
    if (entity != null)
    {
      SqlServer sql = new SqlServer();

      Type tipoEntidade = entity.GetType();

      PropertyInfo[] propriedades = tipoEntidade.GetProperties();

      foreach (PropertyInfo propriedade in propriedades)
      {
        if (propriedade.PropertyType.IsPublic && propriedade.CanWrite && propriedade.PropertyType.Namespace == "System")
        {
          object valor = propriedade.GetValue(entidade, null);

          if (valor != null && propriedade.Name != "ID" && propriedade.Name != "Excluido")
            sql.AdicionarParametro("@" + propriedade.Name, valor);
        }
      }
```

but in Entity Framework i could not implement.

else:

```
public int Save(Anuncio anuncio)
  {
   if (anuncio.Id != 0)
    // ctx.Anuncio.Attach(anuncio);
//attach Error  when othe repository get
//else i need...
{
BancoContext ctx = new BancoContext (); //my Dbcontext
AnuncioAxiliar = ctx.Anuncio.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == entidade.Id); //Entity help

AnuncioAxiliar.Nome = anuncio.Nome;
AnuncioAxiliar.Cliente= anuncio.Cliente;
AnuncioAxiliar.Contrato= anuncio.Contrato;

ctx.SaveChanges(); //vai salvar o AnuncioAxiliar 


}
   else
    ctx.Set(entidade.GetType()).Add(entidade);

   return ctx.SaveChanges();
  }
```

but so i need one Save method for each classe Poco

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

That is common problem. You cannot pass entity loaded from one context to another context. You should share context among your repositories when working in one unit of work (logical transaction). It is also enough to use one repository instance per type in the unit of work.

If you want to pass entity from one context to other context you must first detach it from the first context by calling:

```
ctx.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

Be aware that if entity has any loaded relations these relations will be lost / broken when you detach it from the context.

Comment: but the most case one method in another class will receive the entity save or not and return to first method, making it impossible for me detache

Comment: So use one context for the logical transaction. That is the whole point. Using multiple contexts in this scenario is completely wrong usage.

Answer (score 0):

You need to share the EF db context between your repositories.  When you retrieve data from the database via EF, the object that gets returned by EF is attached to a specific instance of a db context for change tracking.  If you attempt to perform any operations on that entity in another database context, EF will throw an exception as the database context can see it's already attached to another context.

Note that if this is a web application, your db context should only be shared between repositories **in the same web request only**.  If they are shared between all repositories for all web requests, conflicts will occur.

Answer (score 0):

change the constructor of your RepositoryGeneric to accept your data context as a parameter. Then use the same context for all the repositories. You should probably use dependency injection to achieve this.

Something like below

```
    public class RepositoryGeneric<TEntity>
    {
        public RepositoryGeneric(DomainContext domainContext)
        {
            DomainContext = domainContext;         
        }

        protected DomainContext DomainContext { get; private set; }

        protected virtual IDbSet<TEntity> DbSet
        {
            get { return DomainContext.Set<TEntity>(); }
        }

        public virtual TEntity GetByKey(params object[] keys)
        {
            return DbSet.Find(keys);
        }
   }
```